# Uploading File Via HttpWebRequest "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.."

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest, webclient, webrequest

I am running into a error when I try to upload a .xml file to webserver via post.  If I submit the form using a browser this is the header info.

*General*

```
Remote Address:10.0.1.90:80
Request URL:http://10.0.1.90/config/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

*Response Header*

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 09 Oct 2003 16:25:41 GMT
Server:nginx/1.0.5
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

*Request Headers*

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic bWFuYWdlcjptYW5hZ2VyMDE=
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1500
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----    WebKitFormBoundaryEr6fyNPJYuClCcHr
Host:10.0.1.90
Origin:http://10.0.1.90
Referer:http://10.0.1.90/config/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
```

*Request Payload*

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryEr6fyNPJYuClCcHr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="newconfig"; filename="config.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

------WebKitFormBoundaryEr6fyNPJYuClCcHr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="put"

Upload
------WebKitFormBoundaryEr6fyNPJYuClCcHr--
```

This is my c# code I'm using.

```
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(serializedObject); // a json object, or xml, whatever...

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        NetworkCredential up = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        request.Credentials = up;
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8;";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;


        request.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

The error I keep on getting is :"The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."

I don't have access to modify the server where the nginx website is running.

**Update**
 Here is the form html code if it helps anyone help me on this.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">
    <fieldset class="quick_create">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Reset">
        <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Commit">
        <input type="submit" name="apply_reload" value="Commit + Reload">
        <input type="file" name="newconfig">
        <input type="submit" name="put" value="Upload">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**2nd Update (Using the WebClient.UploadFile)**

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
            webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data";
            webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";

            WebRequest serverRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
            serverRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("manager", "manager01");

            WebResponse serverResponse;

            serverResponse = serverRequest.GetResponse();
            serverResponse.Close();

            webClient.UploadFile(url, "POST", data);
            webClient.Dispose();
            webClient = null;
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what's causing your problem but browser uploads use the `multipart/form-data` header for `Content-Type`, whereas you do not.  Try having a look at the 'WebClient.UploadFile' method as it might better suit your needs.

Comment: It might be advisable to delete the `Authorization:Basic` value.

Comment: @LukePark I tried using the WebClient.UploadFile but i get the same result. I include the Form Just encase it may help you or someone.

Comment: @Ulric Not sure what you mean. I am not using Authorization:Basic at all.

Comment: What code did you use for the WebClient?

Comment: @Orlando - In your `Request Headers` section you have a Authorization:Basic section with the 64bit encoded User name / Password.

Comment: @Ulric I can't modify anything on the web server end.

Comment: @Orlando - I am merely trying to point out that you have posted the user name and password on a public forum. I am not asking you to change anything on the server. I am simply suggesting that posting authentication details on a public-facing frequently visited website is probably not recommended. But it is your choice.